# A question on inequality.

Tags: inequality

While  solving a combinatorics problem, I have reached a conjecture that if $\mid N\mid=n\ge 4
,\mid K\mid=k,\mid T\mid=t,\mid K\cap T\mid =q$ where $K,T\subseteq N$ then $$n(k+t)-2(k+t)-2kt+4q\ge 0$$ . I have tried to prove but can't get the wheather the result is true or false

Comment: If we take $n=k=t$ and $q=0$ your inequality becomes $2n^2-4n-2n^2=-4n\geq 0$ which is clearly false, or am I misreading?

Comment: Sorry, I have written incomplete question.You can see the edited question now.

Comment: Well, taking $n=2,k=1=t,K\cap T =\emptyset$ is a counterexample   This is the only counterexample with $K\cap T=\emptyset$ and it may well be the only counterexample.

Comment: but the minimum value of $n$ is $4$

Comment: Yes, I know.  What I meant was:  consider $n=2m, k=t=m, q=0$.  Then the left hand is $n^2-2n-\frac {n^2}2=\frac {n^2}2-2n =2m^2-4m=2m(m-2)$.  For $m=1$ this is negative, but for $m≥2$ it is $≥0$.  I think this is the relevant case to work through but I did not verify that.

Comment: In my question $n\ge 4\Rightarrow m\ge 2$

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  I was trying to break the cases up algebraically.  Like I say, it feels to me that the sort of example I wrote is a "worst case" for your expression but I did not try to prove that and, to be sure, I might have it wrong.